# How do you create front end in Golang? and other questions

Tags: javascript, node.js, go

I started learning programming sometime ago and started with HTML & CSS, finally mastered both of them, now I started using Javascript and learning Javascript. In my learning path I came across Node.js a runtime environment for javascript which basically allows me to have my Html , Css and Javascript into the Node.js environment. Translate to react native and finish coding the whole thing and have a working Web, iOS and Android app. (Haven't done this yet but this is my small understanding about how all this works)

Today I stumbled across Golang...

Loved how simple Golang looks and how easier it is to read than Javascript. I read the differences and similarities , also some tutorials. Now for you Golangers (Gophers?) I have multiple questions.

If I make my app in Golang how do I do the front end? Do I implement html and css? Do I do something else as a visual editor (like Adobe XD as a banal example) ? Do I use React to create the iOS,Android app? Can I use mongoDB(I assume yes as mongoldb was done on Golang, but I still rather ask)?

How does the typical steps in creating an application look like in go?

(Example as with Nodejs web app)
1.Create an Html and CSS UI
2.Add javascript for functionality of the app
3.run on node
4.import into React for iOS and Javascript
5.finish app and deploy

Thank you very much in advance! Golang community seems like a much nicer community than Nodejs community in my opinion.

Ps. Should I drop learning javascript and completely switch to Golang or finish learning Javascript and then learn Golang?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question, which is not really a good fit for `SO`, but having said that: welcome to the wonderful world of `go`! If you want to develop frontend, I'd suggest `vue.js` for reactive frontend & `go` can easily serve streaming backend content.

Comment: Check out [Awesome Go: GUI](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#gui). There's also the promising [gioui.org](https://gioui.org). There is also webassembly (the go compiler can target webassembly), and there are other frameworks where you write only in go and they handle HTTP / HTML / js under the hood (e.g. [gowut](https://github.com/icza/gowut)).

Comment: And there are also lots of [web frameworks](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#web-frameworks). But my advice is that if you're new to Go, first stick to the standard lib, learn to make apps with it, and once you're comfortable with it, then try out other frameworks and libs.

Comment: For the HTML output you can use one of the `template` packages. See [text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) for an introduction, but use [html/template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) for outputting HTML. For styling and front-end functionality you’ll still need CSS and JS.

Answer (score 9):

> If I make my app in Golang how do I do the front end?

I would create the front end using React (note that this is *different* from React *Native*)
and then use Go as your back-end to serve up this React app. You could then also port the front-end to React *Native* in order to have it on iOS and Android.

I have also recently discovered Go and enjoy it, which is why I'd recommend using Go as the
back-end and serving up the React front-end.

Another note on the front end, if you are making it in React I strongly recommend using [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/) - this takes all of the hard work out of configuration, makes it super easy to develop (in development mode it auto-updates the app when you save any changes to source files - super fast). Create React App also then outputs a simple bundle of files which you can then
easily serve up with a Go or Node.js or any other back-end.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank yo so much! I was really hoping for an answer like this one, sadly people blocked my question so others can't find it if they have a similar question as mine

Comment: Glad I could help! I've used quite a few different languages and frameworks etc. Using React and Create-React-App have been the best experience by far. Also, if using React, there is a fantastic UI library called Material UI - might take a bit to get your head around it but then its easy to use and looks slick. FYI I currently personally use Node.js as backend - its simple and handy to write front-end and back-end in js, but looking forward to doing more in Golang.

Answer (score 4):

Front-end needs to be written in JavaScript (and HTML and CSS), there is usually no way around it. The only way you can possibly run Go in the front-end is if you manage to somehow compile Go to JavaScript(or a compilation stack that compiles Go to WASM). I know it's possible to compile C, C++, Rust and C# to JavaScript.

Edit: It's indeed possible to compile Go into JavaScript: https://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs